# fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'imagehlp.lib' installing cx_Freeze

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I'm trying to install cx_Freeze on python 3.4 using:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org cx_freeze
```

However, i'm getting the error

```
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\source 
C:\VS10\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG - IC:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\include /Tcsource/util.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\source/util.obj 
util.c 
C:\VS10\VC\Bin\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Python34\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python34\PCbuild\amd64 imagehlp.lib Shlwapi.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_util build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\source/util.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\cx_Freeze\util.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\source\util.lib     /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\source\util.pyd.manifest 
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'imagehlp.lib' 
error: command 'C:\VS10\VC\Bin\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
```

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current/default version of `cx_Freeze` is 5.1.1, and it supports Python 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6 only.

The latest version of `cx_Freeze` which supports Python 3.4 is 5.0.2. See the `cx_Freeze` [release notes](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes.html) and the `cx-freeze` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cx-freeze/info). So you probably should try

```
pip install [...] cx_Freeze==5.0.2
```

where `[...]` stands for the additional options of your install command.

I'm not sure whether this incompatibility of versions is the root cause of the specific error you have reported, but it will cause issues at some point in your project.